# Formatting Julian days

Tags: sqlite, julian-date

I am using sqlite to record a timestamp

```
INSERT INTO packets VALUES ( strftime('%%J','now') );
```

And then extracting the elapsed time

```
SELECT strftime('%%J','now') - first_timestamp FROM packets;
```

which works well.  If I wait for a minute, the result is 0.0007 ( ~= 1 * 60 / 24 * 60 * 60 )

I would like to see this in hours, minutes and seconds, but

```
sqlite> SELECT time(0.0007);
12:01:00
```

Where did the 12 come from?

This 'works'

```
sqlite> SELECT time(0.0007-0.5);
00:01:00
```

but seems way too wierd to use.

---

Following explanation from CL, I committed this code

```
std::string TimeSinceFirstPacket()
{
    // open database
    Open();

    // read timestamp of first packet
    // this is stored as a Julian day for convenince in calculating and formatting the elapsed time
    // Note that for Julian days
    //   1.0 is 24 hours
    //    -0.5 represents the previous midnight
    // discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/q/38284268/16582

    int dbret = DB.Query(
             " SELECT "
             "       first_timestamp, "
             "       ( strftime('%%J','now') - first_timestamp ) < 1.0, "
             "       time( strftime('%%J','now') - first_timestamp - 0.5 ) "
             " FROM packets;");

    // check for successful db read
    if( dbret != 1 )
        return "error";

    // check that timestamp has been initialized
    if( DB.myResultA[ 0 ] == "0" )
        return "none";

    // check that elapsed time is less than 24 hours
    if( DB.myResultA[ 1 ] == "0" )
        return ">24hr";

    // return human readable hh::mm::ss elapsed time
    return DB.myResultA[ 2 ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julian days do not count from midnight but from noon:

```
> select julianday('2000-01-01 00:00:00');
2451544.5
> select julianday('2000-01-01 12:00:00');
2451545.0
```

So to get the time since midnight, you have to compute the difference between your number, and a number that represents midnight.

Comment: And so the number that represents the previous midnight is -0.5